# play .wav with QSound (Qt) no sound exist

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I tried to play .wav file in Qt by using `QSound::play`

I've tried this code:

```
QSound::play("airplane.wav");
```

No error when build but when run there is no sound?!

Comment: What platform are you running on, and did you make sure there is sound support by checking the result of  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsound.html#isAvailable ?

Answer (score 1):

This rang a bell for me, so I found the code I use to handle sounds.  Our platform is Windows, so this is what works for us.  I wrapped all this up in a player class.  My notes to myself said that QSound wants absolute paths, in platform format (found by examining the QSound code).  So try getting the file path by something like this

```
// (note the "sSoundPath" variable is set to where we store our sound files).
static const QString sSoundPath("./resources/sounds/");
```

elsewhere...

```
//  QSound wants absolute paths, in platform format

QFileInfo fileInfo(soundFile);

if (fileInfo.isRelative())
{
    //  we assume one of our own sound files in a relative path
    fileInfo.setFile(sSoundPath + soundFile);
    fileInfo.makeAbsolute();
}

if (!fileInfo.exists())
{
    return false;
}

mSoundFile = QDir::toNativeSeparators(fileInfo.filePath());
```

Now you can go ahead and try to play the sound file.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent countless days on a similar issue. Basically, I found out that QSound does not support wave files with 44100 Hz sample rate. Check out my discovery at [QT5 QSound does not play all wave files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165608/qt5-qsound-does-not-play-all-wave-files)

A side note, QSound does not support QT resources, in case you are using one. A workaround is to copy the resource into a file, and then play that file with QSound from the hard drive. Hopefully this info helps.