# No Sound Output with QSoundEffect in Qt5.0.2

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to play a wav file if a singal is emitted. For testing i created a pushButton and filled its slot with

```
QSoundEffect alarm;
alarm.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("001.wav"));
alarm.setLoopCount(QSoundEffect::Infinite);
alarm.setVolume(1.0f);
alarm.play();
```

But there is no sound if i click on the pushButton. After searching i found people having the same problem with Qt5 but no solution.

Whats the best and simplest solution with Qt5 to just play an uncompressed sound file (wav) and change its volume?

EDIT: I just found out that it works if i add e.g. a QMessageBox (while this message box is open):

```
QSoundEffect alarm;
alarm.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("001.wav"));
alarm.setLoopCount(2);
alarm.setVolume(0.5f);
alarm.play();

QMessageBox::information(this, "test", "it works");
```

Has anybody an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939759/qaudiodeviceinfo-finds-no-default-audio-device-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

for sound need to write event loop, e.g.:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    QSoundEffect beep;
    beep.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/sound/beep-02.wav"));
    beep.setVolume(1.0f);
    beep.play();
    QEventLoop loop;
    loop.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are under Mac OS X you could try this : [QT5 QSound does not play all wave files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165608/qt5-qsound-does-not-play-all-wave-files)

But the [bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31265) has been reported and should be fixed in Qt 5.1.1, so be patient.

Answer (score 0):

yea, it's buggie.

I recommend to you to use another Audio Converter.

I used this website and it worked afterwards.

http://www.online-convert.com

Comment: Also consider using Audacity for quick conversion. Import all audio files and use "export multiple" feature to generate a set of Wave files that are played flawlessly by `QSoundEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

Your QSoundEffect needs a parent to work correctly, actually it works only when you open the messagebox because it will take it as a parent.